# Please convert curl command line code to PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, paypal

Can someone please help me convert this to PHP code:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-98656197DP057202KKO5NMSY/execute/ \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer A015-m7XgI9uXtd0g4sckNFH3bEaxrAiFlbTecVe9SSgoX4' \
-d '{ "payer_id" : "XMS2L726YHQQY" }'
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$post = json_encode(array('payer_id' => Session::get('paypal_PayerID')));

$curl = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/'.Session::get('paypal_id').'/execute/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: '.Session::get('paypal_token_type').' '.Session::get('paypal_access_token')));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$html = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I have been at it for hours but paypal is not giving me the same reponses, (e.g. it worked two times, but most of the time it returns a 500 error).

Maybe I'm just really loosing it here as it is 2AM in the morning...

And before anyone asks, Yes, I have verified that those session variables have values before sending the curl request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the order of your curl_setopt calls matters behind the scenes. Try placing your CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER call last. You might also consider using Fiddler or something similar to sniff your HTTP requests to easily determine if there are any effectual differences.

Comment: This is getting weirder (I think). I have been testing it for the last 3 hours or so in Google Chrome. I have just switched to Firefox and it returns with a 200 code and the proper response, multiple times. I have made absolutely no changes to the code above...